# bootbox.dialog - The main button is not getting focus when using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, jquery, focus, scriptmanager, bootbox

I am using bootbox for displaying dialog boxes. When I am trying to put the implementation in JavaScript it is working fine

```js
  $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    bootbox.dialog({
                           message: "my message.",
                           title: "<i class='fa fa-times-circle red'></i> Error!",
                           buttons: {
                               main: {
                                   label: "Got It!",
                                   className: "btn btn-success btn-primary"
                                  
                               }
                           }
                       });
      });
```

In the above case the button automatically focused so that we can press enter key to close it.

But Since, I have some values to be inserted as parameter I have decided to make a C# function and implement it

```html
public void ShowMessagebox(string msg,string type,Page mypage)
        {
            string title="";
            switch(type)
            {
                case "success":
                    title="<i class='fa fa-check-circle green'></i> <span class='green'> Success!</span>";
                    break;
                case "error":
                    title="<i class='fa fa-times-circle red'></i> Error!";
                    break;
                case "info":
                    title="<i class='fa fa-info-circle orange2'></i> Information!";
                    break;
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(mypage, this.GetType(), "myfunction", "bootbox.dialog({message: \"" + msg + "\",title: \"" + title + "\",buttons: { main: {label: \"Got It!\",className: \"btn-primary btn-success\"}}});", true);
        }
```

Now this will work fine. But my problem is that the button is not getting focus and I cannot close the dialog by pressing enter key.

Even I have put $(".btn-primary").focus() but no use!.

Can anyone please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

I just wrapped the code with jquery ready function and it worked!

Thank you